# MySQL Workbench has encountered a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m. MySQL doesn't start Windows 7

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have MySQL workbench installed on my computer and always worked correctly. Now try to run it and do not run. Gives an error:

> MySql Workbench has encountered a problem
>   External component has throw an exception.
>
> We are sorry for the inconvenience but an unexpected exception has been raised by one of the MySQL Workbench modules. In order to fix this issue we would kindly ask you to file a bug report. You can do that by pressing the [Report Bug] button below.
>
> Please make sure to include a detailed description of your actions that lead to this problem.
>
> Thanks a lot for taking the time to help us improve MySQL Workbench!
>
> The MySQL Workbench Team

And then the application crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I saved off a "new" .sql file while in Workbench. I exited Workbench.  When launched again is when I got the error.

For some reason I looked at the folder I saved the .sql file in and noticed it was 0kb in size.  I deleted this file and re-launched Workbench ... it launched normally.

Comment: Tkank you so much. You save my day.

Comment: I need to wait 4 minutes and I do that ;)
Thanks again

Comment: This bug has been solved already a while ago. What version of MySQL Workbench do you use now? I recommend to keep your local copy always at the latest (GA) version.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ....

Because your computer doesn't have Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Problem resolved]

**MySQL Workbench has encountered a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m**

same error i got it

**Reason-**

i don't have enough space in my drive.

**Solution**

I had deleted and moved  some files.
Start Mysql Workbench it start working as expected

When it start mysql workbench all database schema will be empty

**All database restored in mysql workbench**

Restart the mysql80 service

1. Goto control pannel
2. Click on Administrative tools
3. Select Mysql80 and click on start button
4. Re-open the mysql workbench

It shows all your data

You can solved the above error with this steps

Answer (score 0):

Company's firewall was causing the issue. I connected to personal wifi connection, that fixed the issue.