# MySQL workbench not connecting with database

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm working on a project with MySQL. I've downloaded and installed `MySQL` from `oracle` website. I've installed MySQL workbench `version 6.3.4.0 build 829 (64 bit)`, and configured MySQL server at `localhost, on 1527 port`. But when I try to connect the database with `workbench` It pops up this message screen:

[image: ERROR IMAGE]

I've studied and searched for this problem from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530390/mysql-workbench-has-encountered-a-problemm-mysql-doesnt-start-windows-7), [HERE](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75344), [HERE](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77880), [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078528/mysql-workbench-not-conntecting-to-database) and many other tutorials and websites, But I'm still Unable to connect with database.
I've studied the prerequisites for `workbench` so I installed following component:

[image: Installed Software]

I've `Windows 10 (64 bit)` operating system.
So tell me how to solve this problem.

**INFO:**

1. I'm `able` to connect this database using `JAVA and JDBC`.
2. `Workbench` works `fine` on other computer having `Windows 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the very exact bug described in here. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75673/https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75344

can you try to replace the old `HtmlRenderer.dll` with the new one that you can obtain here https://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=22868&bug_id=75673 and then, try re-run the workbench again.

The dll should be located in `Program Files` > `MySql` > `[your workbench folder]`

Comment: Can u tell me why this happen even I've installed fresh copy of MySQL and workbench

Comment: well, looking at the changes history, your version is released on 2015-06-15. While, the new library which include the fixes (`HtmlRenderer.dll`) is created on 21 June. Nothing is wrong with the MySql, just fixes that is not included with the version 6.3.4

Comment: Now I wonder more, because same version and same installation file works on another computer having same configuration except CPU.

Comment: then it could be because the other pc has font family that you don't have. Because the bug is about setting up available font for html renderer